# Selected Visual studio is missing required components and may be not be able to build generate project

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Build a simple project of unity "hello world", Unity says me:

> Selected Visual studio is missing required components and may be not be able to build generate project

¿Any idea why get this message?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Give this a try:

1. Open the Visual Studio 2017 Installer
2. Click "Modify"
3. Select and install the optional **Package C++ Universal Windows Platform tools** from **Universal Windows Platform development**

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked for me running Unity 2019.4.0f1 & Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Worked for Unity 2021.3.141f & Visual Studio 2022